# Angular Routing in md-nav-bar

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-routing, ngroute

I have my html pages stored in the wwwroot folder under the partials subfolder. I want to load these html files(which is in partials folder) and view it in index.cshtml(located in Views Folder) using ngRoute.

Here is my code for index.cshtml (Note: I am building a .Net Core Web App).

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak ng-controller="indexController">
<div class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar aria-label="navmenu">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#main" name="main">
            Main
        </md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#other1" name="other1">
            Other1
        </md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#other2" name="other2">
            Other2
        </md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

This is my script

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngAria']);

 myapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/other1', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/other1.html',
            controller: 'other1Ctrl'
        })
        .when('/other2', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/other2.html',
            controller: 'other2Ctrl'
        });
});
myapp.controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Index Controller"
});

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Main"
});

myapp.controller('other1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "other 1"
});

myapp.controller('other2Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "other 2"
});
```

My problem is, the other1 and other2 html files does not load, it just loads my main file in the ng-view.

Comment: I think all md-nav-item tag should be in `ng-view` div. i,e `<div ng-view>//your main and other 1 md-nav-item tags </div>`

Comment: your order1.html will be shown in the url, `your_url/order1'`
`eg: localhost/your_project/order1'`

Comment: yes, if i type manually the URL it does load, but when I click on the md-nav-item it doesn't